# Get EntitySetName from EntityName in WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a EnityName called Client and I need it's collection name Clients, it has to be generic so that I can get the EntitySetName from EntityName for any entity. It's exposed in the svc file but doesn't seem to be in the service proxy class. If I can do this then I can have a generic method like.

```
public void Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> entitySet)
{
    var myService = GetServiceContext();

    foreach (var entity in entitySet)
    {
        myService.AddObject(entity.GetType().Name -- NEEDS TO BE ENTITY SET NAME, entity);
    }

    myService.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I implemented it:

```
    private static string ResolveEntitySet(Type type)
    {
        var entitySetAttribute =
            (EntitySetAttribute) type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (EntitySetAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();

        if (entitySetAttribute != null)
        {
            return entitySetAttribute.EntitySet;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

An a quick example of calling it (similar to yours, but with a single add):

```
    public void Add<T>(T entity)
    {
        _entities.AddObject(ResolveEntitySet(entity.GetType()), entity);
    }
```

Here a peak at how my "Account" entity looks in my proxy class (auto generated in .NET 4 - I didn't have to add this, but it looks like older versions might???)

```
[System.Data.Services.Common.EntitySetAttribute("Accounts")]
[System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKeyAttribute("Id")]
public partial class Account : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the EntitySetAttribute doesn't exist on the client proxy class. I made sure that I added the EntitySetAttribute for each entity in the Service. Did you have to do anything specific to get it to work with the client? Also what version of WCF Data Services are you using?

Comment: I'm on .Net Framework 4.  I didn't have to do anything to my proxy class as the EntitySetAttribute was already there.  Glad to here this helped!